# fetch latest message from sql DB based on timestamp by ignore failed one

Tags: sql, oracle

here in my DB for shipment, 12456 there are many records to which we have status code as 1000 (success) or 1001 (failed) and I want to pull a report for the given list of shipments Ids to which

If the latest record in DB contains status code  1000 then ignore else display me data in the select query. Should be able to add an additional filter based on a message where if record contains a specific text, just ignore in the report

How to modify the query. I am new to this area

```
select createdDate, , status_code, message from SHIPMENT_DATA
where shipmentid in (
'12456'
)
```

sample data

```
TimeStamp                               ShipmentId  StatusCode      Message
####################################################################################################
03-NOV-20 07.15.28.951000000 AM         12456       1000            error message
03-NOV-20 06.15.28.951000000 AM         222         1001            error message
03-NOV-20 05.15.28.951000000 AM         12456       1001            Success
03-NOV-20 04.15.28.951000000 AM         333         1000            Success
```

here for shipment, 12456 have latest message status code as 1000, dont pull in port and display rest 2 record.

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: Your sample doesn't have "latest record". It has 2 records with the exact same TimeStamp for 12456.

Comment: @JamesZ  - data is fixed

Answer (score 0):

If you want the detail for unsuccessful shipments, you can use `first_value()`:

```
select shipment_id, createdDate, status_code, message
from (select sd.*,
             first_value(status_code) over (partition by shipment_id order by createdDate desc) as last_status_code
      from SHIPMENT_DATA sd
      where shipmentid in ('12456')
     ) sd
where last_status_code <> 1000;
```

Comment: Hi @Gordon.. not working for me. its not picking up SD.